# Delete/Drop only the rows which has all values as NaN in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe, i need to drop the rows which has all the values as NaN.

```
ID      Age    Gender
601     21       M
501     NaN      F
NaN     NaN      NaN
```

The resulting data frame should look like.

```
Id     Age    Gender
601     21      M
501    NaN      F
```

I used df.drop(axis = 0), this will delete the rows if there is even one NaN value in row. Is there a way to do as required?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The complete command is this:

```
df.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all', inplace = True)
```

you must add `inplace = True` argument, if you want the dataframe to be actually updated. Alternatively, you would have to type:

```
df = df.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all')
```

but that's less pythonic IMHO.

Comment: `inplace` is **not** recommended and will actually be removed in future versions: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529

Comment: Good point. Obviously when I wrote this reply the use of `inplace` was not deprecated.

Comment: @tdy Interesting that issue was from 2017 and in 2023 `inplace` has not been deprecated.

Comment: @mp252 `inplace` has been inadvisable since 2017, but it won't start being "deprecated" (formally in the API) until the [PDEP-8](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/51466) proposal gets merged.

Comment: Good to know! Looks like I have got a lot of refactoring to do!

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
df.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all')
```